# Infinite loop in Bubblesort implementation

Tags: sml

I'm trying to create a recursive bubble sort in SML using 'let in end' to contain helper functions.

I'm rather lost when it comes to why it won't print anything.

main.sml:

```
val master = [1,2,3,1,4,2,8,3,2,1]: int list;

fun bubblesort ( x : int list) : int list = 
    let
        fun sort [] = []
          | sort [a] = [a]
          | sort (a::b::c) = if (a < b) then [a]@sort(b::c) else [b]@sort(a::c)

        fun issorted [] = true  
          | issorted [x] = true 
          | issorted (x::y::t) = x <= y andalso issorted(y::t)
    in
        sort x;
        if issorted x then x else bubblesort x;
        x
    end;

val result = bubblesort master
```

Result:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.78 [built: Thu Aug 31 03:45:42 2017]
val master = [1,2,3,1,4,2,8,3,2,1] : int list 
val bubblesort = fn :int list -> int list
=
```

[image: My code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are thinking imperatively, as if `sort x` *mutates x*. In your current code, it is the original, unsorted `x` which is used in the line which begins `if issorted x ...`. If that `x` is unsorted, then you are forever calling `bubblesort` on that original value. In fact, since that code is trying to return `x` itself (by having `x` on the final line of the `in` block) you will be forever calling `bubblesort` on the same value even if `x` is sorted.  Instead, you need to use the *value* `sort x` in the comparison, preferably by first capturing it in a `val` binding, and return the value of the `if`, rather than `x` itself. The following works:

```
fun bubblesort ( x : int list) : int list = 

    let
        fun sort [] = []
                |sort [a] = [a]
                |sort(a::b::c) = if (a < b) then a::sort(b::c) else b::sort(a::c);

        fun issorted [] = true  
          | issorted [x] = true 
          | issorted (x::y::t) = x <= y andalso issorted(y::t);

        val y = sort x;
    in
       if issorted y then y else bubblesort y
    end;
```

Then:

```
- bubblesort master;
val it = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,8] : int list
```

Note that I replaced `[a]@sort(b::c)` by the more idomatic `a::sort(b::c)`.